# Calculating packet size in datagram network

Tags: networking, lan

In a datagram network a packet travels from node A to D on the following route: A → B → C → D. Each link has data rate of 1 Mbps. The total end-to-end delay (from A to D) is 0.4 s. The total waiting time on the route is 0.25 s and the total propagation delay is 0.12 s. What is the  packet length expressed in bits ? I'm not sure how exactly to find this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the units, subtract all the latencies from the total time so that what you have left is attributable to the bandwidth. Multiply the result in seconds by the bandwidth in bits/second and the result is in bits. However I'm not convinced this is really a valid procedure.